# Does C++11 allow (not require) release/acquire semantics for volatile keyword

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Since Visual C++ 2005, Microsoft has made additional ordering guarantees for accesses to `volatile` types which are not required by the C++ Standard.

Does anything in the C++ Standard actually forbid these guarantees?  [The Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd.aspx) seems to think so.

Please let me know whether the Standard allows the ordering implemented by Microsoft, and also vote on this bug report:

- [`/volatile:ms` documentation mangles what "ISO compliant" means](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/767448/volatile-ms-documentation-mangles-what-iso-compliant-means)

Comment: Also the MSDN documentation states, in the section *ISO Compliant*:  "The volatile keyword in C++11 ISO Standard code is to be used only for hardware access; do not use it for inter-thread communication."  To my eyes this implies that according to the C++03 Standard `volatile` is to be used for inter-process communication.  Is that what they are implying?

Comment: @John: I believe they are using the phrase "C++11 ISO Standard code" to mean "portable code that works correctly with any C++11 compiler".  Use of `volatile` for threading (inter- or intra-process) has never been portable.  BTW the C++03 Standard doesn't discuss processes or threading much at all.

Comment: @John: I don't think they intend to imply that. They're comparing conforming C++11 programs with programs intended for their implementations of C++11 and C++03 with the semantics of /volatile:ms. They aren't comparing C++11 with C++03.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An implementation is certainly allowed to do things beyond on what is required as long as it meets the requirements set forth by the standard. Adding release/acquire semantics to `volatile` object is definitely within scope. I don't think there is interest in the C++ committee to change the semantics (we are just starting a new week of discussing C++ in Portland with Herb right now talking about how to organize the meeting).

Comment: All `volatile` requires is that every read to a `volatile` object results in an actual read and that every write to a `volatile` object result in an actual write. This can be augmented by what every memory visibility facility they want to add: the standard makes just a few requirements on effects on I/O and `volatile` variables as its observable behavior. Adding release/acquire semantics to `volatile` will not reduce guarantees on the observable behavior. Of course, to actually observe change to `volatile` object you need to observed it from the outside of the program.

Comment: That's what I thought.  So, in summary "Acquire/release guarantees on volatile variables are permitted but not required.  Code that relies on such guarantees will be non-portable."

Comment: @BenVoigt: Note that the fact that an implementation can add guarantees to the standard does not imply that a program that depends on those extra guarantees is standard-compliant (your program can still have Undefined Behavior according to the standard even though in that particular implementation the behavior might be fully defined)

Comment: @David: The *compiler* is compliant... it provides all guarantees required by the Standard and correctly compiles and executes code written against the Standard (i.e. the behavior is well-defined according to the Standard).  We're not arguing that it's a bad idea to include a note about implementation-specific behavior and portability in the documentation.  The question is whether the behavior is "non-ISO Compliant".

Comment: Agreed, the point is that while the compiler is allowed to add extra guarantees, it is dangerous to depend on them and you will generate programs whose behavior is not guaranteed by the standard (i.e. will work in one platform/compiler fail in others). In other words: beware when using extensions and in particular when it comes to multithreading guarantees, if you later compile the code in a different place it will compile and introduce a hard to debug issue.

Comment: @David: Exactly what I think too.  And as a rule Microsoft uses "Microsoft Specific" to flag those non-portable cases.  But the documentation currently says "Microsoft Specific (non-ISO Compliant)", which is supposed to mean that strictly conforming code will misbehave on the Microsoft compiler (conditioned on that compile option of course), and that isn't the case here.

Comment: Being at the meeting allows to quickly poll people: The Microsoft people I talked to said that it is a "doc bug" to call it non-conforming. They think it is a conforming extension but none users should rely on (there were committee members overhearing the discussion who consider the behavior a misfeature).

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Awesome.  The doc bug is linked in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The standard requires that *access to volatile objects is evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine*, which means roughly "don't optimize", but no more than that. For example, the compiler is not allowed to cache a value in a register or perform common subexpression elimination. It has to do exactly what you tell it.

Thus, for all the standard cares, `volatile` has `memory_order_relaxed` semantics (it doesn't specify anything different). This doesn't mean you are not allowed to implement something more strict, of course.

The Microsoft compiler has always (*since 2005* as Ben Voigt points out) treated `volatile` as acquire/release, which lead to many people assuming "volatile == threadsafe", which in return led to many articles turning this around into "volatile is useless!" and "volatile is evil".

The likely reason why MS recommends to use the ISO implementation is that this makes their compiler behave like every other compiler, no more nasty surprises.

Comment: So using `/volatile:iso` magically finds all race conditions?  "Nasty surprises" when moving between implementations are common, and getting rid of the acquire/release semantics does nothing to change that.  What it does change is that the optimizer is free to emit faster code sequences.

Comment: Also, the Microsoft compiler hasn't always treated `volatile` as acquire/release, it started to do so in Visual C++ 2005 (like I said in the question).

Comment: No, it does not "magically" do anything (this is what many people used to think about the `volatile` keyword). `/volatile:iso` just makes the compiler behave like all others, which is less confusing. Your code doesn't suddenly behave incorrectly if you compile it with something else, because you don't rely on "magic".

Comment: No two compilers behave exactly alike.  There's always a chance that a race condition is hidden by a particular implementation.  Just because code passes tests under `/volatile:iso` doesn't mean it's strictly conforming, so "no more nasty surprises" just isn't meaningful.

Comment: It's meaningful insofar as you have to explicitly use the semantics you need, if you need anything else but "relaxed". Therefore people will not assume that it's just good, and in 2-3 years from now, the "volatile == threadsafe" fallacy will be forgotten, which is a really big nasty surprise when you fall for it.

Comment: Except when using `volatile` accidentally works, even with `/volatile:iso`... which it often will.  And people will just assume it's good.

Comment: Another thing to note is that Microsoft didn't cause the "`volatile` is threadsafe" fallacy.  They changed the behavior in VC++ 2005 because of all the code already being written based on that fallacy.

Comment: @BenVoigt: they missed a trick then, to instead emit a warning, "you seem to be using `volatile`, have you considered a critical section?"

Comment: @SteveJessop: A substantial amount of broken code (using `volatile`) does not equate to most code using `volatile` being broken.  Such messages with high false positive rates belong in static analysis tools, not compiler warnings (although Visual C++ `/analyze` does blend the two).

Comment: @BenVoigt: yeah, they might have to tweak the exact conditions under which the warning is issued. Not every `volatile`. But I suspect there are certain uses of `volatile` objects that in practice are pretty much always wrong, such as a `volatile` global `int`. And as a separate issue of "blame" (not that I really care who's at fault if anyone), if MS had felt that this behavior was a mis-feature, as others do, they could have added it but not made it the default, and warned only in default mode not "I know what I'm doing mode".

Comment: @Steve: A `volatile` global `int` (combined with linker directives to place that symbol at a fixed memory location) is precisely what using `volatile` correctly (for memory-mapped hardware access) often looks like.

Comment: @Ben: probably best to emit the warning when the linker directives aren't there, then.